# What does $\partial A$ mean?

Tags: analysis, notation

I'm having trouble understanding what $\partial S$ means in analysis?

Let S be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.  Show that $\partial$ S is closed;

Just curious what the partial symbol means in this case.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Depends on context. For example, border of set $A$.

Comment: Could be the boundary  of a set A

Comment: This question really [Stokes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Stokes_theorem) the flames of memory.

Comment: It the given context, it is the boundary. In fact, boundaries are topologically closed always; this isn’t just a statement about $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Agree with the above comment, most likely topological boundary is all you have to worry about here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology) While in some contexts it has a more complicated meaning (e.g. boundary of a manifold https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Manifold_with_boundary as mentioned by another comment), here (for an analysis course) it almost certain means just the closure minus the interior.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely $\partial A$ denotes the boundary of $A$; that is, the closure of $A$ minus the interior of $A$. For example, the boundary of the interval $(0,1]$ is $[0,1]\setminus(0,1)=\{0\}\cup\{1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The topological boundary $\partial S$ of a subset $S$ of a topological space $X$ can be defined as the intersection of the closure and the complement of the interior, i.e.
$$
\partial S := \overline{S} \cap (S^\circ)^C
$$
since both are closed so is their intersection.

Answer (score 0):

The $\partial S$ is usually denote by the boundary of a set in analysis, and in analysis usually talk $\partial S$ about some subset of $R^n$, $\partial S$ means the set which element have the property that any neighbourhood of the element have some point of $S$ and the some point of the complement set of $S$.

when $S$ is a subset of $R$, The cluster point set of $\partial S$,denoted by $A$, any element of $A$,any neighbourhood of the element contain a element of $\partial S$, then contain a neighbourhood of the element of $\partial S$,so contain  some point of $S$ and the some point of the complement set of $S$,so belongs to $\partial S$,so it's closed.